# Python virtualenv questions

Tags: python, windows, linux, virtualenv

I'm using VirtualEnv on Windows XP. I'm wondering if I have my brain wrapped around it correctly:

I ran `virtualenv ENV` and it created `C:\WINDOWS\system32\ENV`. I then changed my `PATH` variable to include `C:\WINDOWS\system32\ENV\Scripts` instead of `C:\Python27\Scripts`. Then, I checked out Django into `C:\WINDOWS\system32\ENV\Lib\site-packages\django-trunk`, updated my `PYTHON_PATH` variable to point the new Django directory, and continued to `easy_install` other things (which of course go into my new `C:\WINDOWS\system32\ENV\Lib\site-packages` directory).

I understand why I should use VirtualEnv so I can run multiple versions of Django, and other libraries on the same machine, but does this mean that to switch between environments I have to basically change my `PATH` and `PYTHON_PATH` variable? So, I go from developing one Django project which uses Django 1.2 in an environment called `ENV` and then change my `PATH` and such so that I can use an environment called `ENV2` which has the dev version of Django?

Is that basically it, or is there some better way to automatically do all this (I could update my path in Python code, but that would require me to write machine-specific code in my application)?

Also, how does this process compare to using VirtualEnv on Linux (I'm quite the beginner at Linux).

Comment: Have trouble activating a `virtualenv` on Windows? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713789/3491991)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Normally `virtualenv` creates environments in the current directory. Unless you're intending to create virtual environments in `C:\Windows\system32` for some reason, I would use a different directory for environments.

You shouldn't need to mess with paths: use the `activate` script (in `<env>\Scripts`) to ensure that the Python executable and path are environment-specific. Once you've done this, the command prompt changes to indicate the environment. You can then just invoke easy_install and whatever you install this way will be installed into this environment. Use `deactivate` to set everything back to how it was before activation.

Example:

```
c:\Temp>virtualenv myenv
New python executable in myenv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools..................done.
c:\Temp>myenv\Scripts\activate
(myenv) C:\Temp>deactivate
C:\Temp>
```

Notice how I didn't need to specify a path for `deactivate` - `activate` does that for you, so that when activated "Python" will run the Python in the virtualenv, not your system Python. (Try it - do an `import sys; sys.prefix` and it should print the root of your environment.)

You can just activate a new environment to switch between environments/projects, but you'll need to specify the whole path for `activate` so it knows which environment to activate. You shouldn't ever need to mess with PATH or PYTHONPATH explicitly.

If you use Windows Powershell then you can take advantage of a [wrapper](https://bitbucket.org/guillermooo/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/). On Linux, the `virtualenvwrapper` (the link points to a port of this to Powershell) makes life with `virtualenv` even easier.

**Update:** Not incorrect, exactly, but perhaps not quite in the spirit of `virtualenv`. You could take a different tack: for example, if you install Django and anything else you need for your site in your virtualenv, then you could work in your project directory (where you're developing your site) with the virtualenv activated. Because it was activated, your Python would find Django and anything else you'd easy_installed into the virtual environment: and because you're working in your project directory, your project files would be visible to Python, too.

**Further update:** You should be able to use `pip`, `distribute` instead of `setuptools`, and just plain `python setup.py install` with `virtualenv`. Just ensure you've activated an environment before installing something into it.

Comment: thanks. How does this deal with my `PYTHONPATH`? For instance, I have my project directory in `PYTHONPATH`, and I have Django's directory in there. Is this incorrect to do?

Comment: thanks for the update. BTW, does `virtualenv` only work with `easy_install`? I worked with a company a couple months back who preferred using `pip` over `easy_install`. Is that a whole different camp, or is `easy_install` sort of the standard way to install Python libraries now?

Comment: I had to 'cd /Scripts' first, then I typed 'activate'

Comment: If i try to activate the virtual environment it answers with: "You must 'source' this script: PS> . .\activate  ---- but nothing happens

Answer (score 6):

Yes basically this is what virtualenv do , and this is what the `activate` command is for, from the doc [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv):

> activate script
>
> In a newly created virtualenv there
>   will be a bin/activate shell script,
>   or a Scripts/activate.bat batch file
>   on Windows.
>
> This will change your $PATH to
>   point to the virtualenv bin/
>   directory. Unlike workingenv, this is
>   all it does; it's a convenience. But
>   if you use the complete path like
>   /path/to/env/bin/python script.py you
>   do not need to activate the
>   environment first. You have to use
>   source because it changes the
>   environment in-place. After activating
>   an environment you can use the
>   function deactivate to undo the
>   changes.
>
> The activate script will also modify
>   your shell prompt to indicate which
>   environment is currently active.

so you should just use `activate` command which will do all that for you:

```
> \path\to\env\bin\activate.bat
```

Comment: do I use `activate` for one terminal instance? Or, does it permanently change my path?

Comment: also, what about my `PYTHON_PATH`? I have Django on there, and my project directory. When I run `activate` how will this help all that, or will it?

Comment: @orokusaki: yes for one terminal instance. and you don't have to change __PYTHONPATH__;  __activate.bat__ will do it for you, hope my explanation was good :)

Answer (score 3):

on Windows I have python 3.7 installed and I still couldn't activate `virtualenv` from Gitbash with `./Scripts/activate` although it worked from Powershell after running `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in Powershell and changing the setting to "Yes To All".

I don't like Powershell and I like to use Gitbash, so to activate `virtualenv` in Gitbash first navigate to your project folder, use `ls` to list the contents of the folder and be sure you see "Scripts". Change directory to "Scripts" using `cd Scripts`, once you're in the "Scripts" path use `. activate` to activate `virtualenv`. Don't forget the space after the dot.

Comment: Git Bash should work fine with `. venv/Scripts/activate` (NOTE: there is a space after the period!!) or `source venv/Scripts/activate`, at least working for me. This is either directly with Git Bash or from the VS Code Terminal window (where I've selected Bash).

Answer (score 1):

After creating virtual environment copy the activate.bat file from Script folder of python and paste to it your environment and open cmd from your virtual environment and run activate.bat file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bevpb.png)

Answer (score 0):

in my project wsgi.py file i have this code (it works with virtualenv,django,apache2 in windows and python 3.4)

```
import os
import sys
DJANGO_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'..')
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PATH)
sys.path.append('c:/myproject/env/Scripts')
sys.path.append('c:/myproject/env/Lib/site-packages')
activate_this = 'c:/myproject/env/scripts/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read())
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

in virtualhost file conf i have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / c:/myproject/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
    DocumentRoot c:/myproject/myproject/
    <Directory  "c:/myproject/myproject/myproject/">
       Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
      Require local
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In windows:**
Press Windows (or Windows+R) and then type “cmd”:  Run the Command Prompt in normal mode.

1. `cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserProjectName> pip install virtualenv`
2. For Create a venv run this  `virtualenv -p python3 venv`
3. Activate virtualenv `venv\Scripts\activate`
4. It will look like this `(venv) C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserDjangoProject>`
5. Then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`
6. Show the installed package `pip list`