# How to configure virtual environment hooks before or after activating the virtual environment, and before or after deactivating it in Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv

I am new to Django. I have created the virtual environment. With virtualenvwrapper, there is a way to configure different hooks that are sourced before or after activating the virtual environment, and before or after deactivating it, but I am not sure how to do this. I am using Windows for this. There is a lot of help for this in Linux but I can't find anything for Windows.

Comment: How to define VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR variable in windows

Answer (score 0):

*Since you are using windows you should read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528057/5658350) before.
Once finished and decided to use tools such as [powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell), you can do as follow:*

in your **virtualenv directory** you will find your app folders, under `virtualenv_path/app/bin` you find all the hooks:

**Example**: You need to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to tell django use my local setting, you need to set it in each activation of the env and unset it when you deactive the env:

in **`postactive`** file add : `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="myproject.settings_local"`

and in **`predeactivate`**  you add: `unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

So the variable will be set every time you activate your env and unset every tine you deactivate. 
To check if every thing is working correct when you activate your env try in shell:

```
echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

Comment: you still can do it if you use tools like [powershell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell). I updated the post, check the link.