# How to activate virtual environment from Windows 10 command prompt

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtual-environment

I'm trying to create and activate a virtual environment, using Windows 10 command prompt. I know that virtualenv is installed correctly, as the command

```
virtualenv venv
```

Works. I've navigated to my virtualenv download, Downloads\venv\Scripts, and am trying to activate my virtual environment venv. I've tried

```
venv activate
```

Which doesn't work since Windows doesn't recognize venv as a command. I've also tried

```
virtualenv venv activate
```

Which also doesn't work since virtualenv is saying that "venv activate" isn't a valid argument.

Comment: this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527958/python-virtualenv-questions

Answer (score 55):

Use the `activate` script in the Scripts directory of your virtual environment:

```
> venv\Scripts\activate
```

This will activate your virtual environment and your terminal will look like this depending on the directory you're in:

```
(venv) C:\Users\acer\Desktop>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: $ venv\Scripts\activate
bash: venvScriptsactivate: command not found

Comment: Using bash I think what you can do is `. venv/Scripts/activate` Do note that there is a space after the dot.

Comment: In Windows10 cmd it has to be ```.\venv\Scripts\activate```

Answer (score 9):

from the command (`cmd`) prompt:

```
call venv/Scripts/activate
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `virtualenvwrapper-win`, and using the DOS command prompt (as opposed to e.g. Powershell), then new virtualenvs are created using:

```
mkvirtualenv myenv
```

and activated using

```
workon myenv
```

You should define the environment variable `WORKON_HOME` to point to where you want you virtualenvs to reside.

If you've installed `virtualenvwrapper-win>=1.2.4` then the `virtualenvwrapper` command will give you a list available commands:

```
go|c:\srv> virtualenvwrapper

 virtualenvwrapper is a set of extensions to Ian Bicking's virtualenv
 tool.  The extensions include wrappers for creating and deleting
 virtual environments and otherwise managing your development workflow,
 making it easier to work on more than one project at a time without
 introducing conflicts in their dependencies.

 virtualenvwrapper-win is a port of Dough Hellman's virtualenvwrapper to Windows
 batch scripts.

 Commands available:

   add2virtualenv: add directory to the import path

   cdproject: change directory to the active project

   cdsitepackages: change to the site-packages directory

   cdvirtualenv: change to the $VIRTUAL_ENV directory

   lssitepackages: list contents of the site-packages directory

   lsvirtualenv: list virtualenvs

   mkproject: create a new project directory and its associated virtualenv

   mkvirtualenv: Create a new virtualenv in $WORKON_HOME

   rmvirtualenv: Remove a virtualenv

   setprojectdir: associate a project directory with a virtualenv
   toggleglobalsitepackages: turn access to global site-packages on/off

   virtualenvwrapper: show this help message

   whereis: return full path to executable on path.

   workon: list or change working virtualenvs
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to the folder where you have created the virtual environment in cmd and
enter the command `.\venv\Scripts\activate`
It will activate the virtual env in windows

Answer (score 3):

From the directory where you have your virtual environment (e.g. `myenv`)

you need to run the following command: `.\myenv\Scripts\activate`

Answer (score 2):

When you use "virtualenv" to create an env, it saves an "activate.bat" file in the scripts folder originating from the directory you ran the first command. E.g if you ran the command `virtualenv env` from `C:/Users/Name/Documents/...`, the .bat will be located in `C:/Users/Name/Documents/.../env/scripts/activate.bat`. You can run it from there.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me from Anaconda prompt,

```py
.\\myvenv\\Scripts\\activate.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Python Scripts folder is in your environment variables.

Usually the path is: "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts"
(Change "admin" to your windows username and "Python37-32" path according to your python version)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can activate your virtualenv using command: `workon myenvname`

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a command-line script like this -

```
@echo off
CD\
CD "C:\Users\[user name]\venv\Scripts" 
start activate.bat
start jupyter notebook
```

Save this in a notepad file with an extension ".cmd".
You are ready to go

Answer (score 0):

if you have anaconda installed then open **anaconda terminal** and type

```
> conda env list              # for list of environment you already have
> conda activate {env_name}   # to activate the environment
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I followed in order to create virtual environment in Windows without any error:

1. `python -m venv (virtual-env-name)`
2. `.\(virtual-env-name)\Scripts\activate`

Note: There is no space in between `.` and `\`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before posting an answer, try to check the other answers for duplicate answers that are the same as yours.

Answer (score -1):

first open a command line. Then drop active.bat file from this address to your command line.

address:

```
your virtual environment name/Scripts/
```

Answer (score -3):

1. start python 3.7
2. `python -m virtualenv`
   `"You must provide a DEST_DIR"`
3. `python -m venv demodjango("demodjango is file name)"`
4. `activate.bat`
5. `pip install django`
6. `django-admin.py startproject demo1` (demo1 is my project)
7. `python manage.py runserver`
   `Performing system checks...`
8. After doing this on a command prompt, you will get an URL. Click on that and you will see a message in the browser window that Django has been properly installed.