# How do I activate a virtual environment using a shell script on windows 10?

Tags: python, bash, shell, windows-10, virtualenv

I am trying to activate a venv and then run a python script using a .sh or .cmd script.

so far ive got:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd venv
cd Scripts
activate.bat <- breaks here

cd v:
python test.py
```

however this doesn't work :( Ive searched online but I can only see solutions for linux.

venv to activate and python script to run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to activate virtual environment from Windows 10 command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896093/how-to-activate-virtual-environment-from-windows-10-command-prompt)

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks here"? Do you get an error message? Maybe you want to stick to Windows (write a batch file instead of a SH script).