# How can I get into folders and out of them in CMD?

Tags: python, django

I have saw a question about activating virtualenv in Django (Virtual Environment), I took action with the first answer.
Here's the link:
[How to activate Virtual Environment in DJango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142774/how-to-activate-virtual-environment-in-django)
The answer is for "Shariful Islam"...
The first step was this:

```
cd C:\Users\User\Desktop\UserDjangoProject> pip install virtualenv
```

I wasn't able to operate this command in CMD (as he said at the answer's heading).
Can anyone help me in that?

Comment: You would need to change the `User` part of that pathname to your actual username.

Comment: That was my actual username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the correct code is : cd Desktop\UserDjangoProject and press ENTER.

To get out of the folder in cmd, press cd .. (two dots)

ps: You dont need to get into your folder to pip install something.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that I had to install virtualenv first, then cd to the actual project directory, and then use the activate script and install Django. Once done, it was finally the time to start the Django project.