# I tried to install django using pip install django but still i am getting this error any comments

Tags: python, django, api, rest

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\emin\Desktop\fliteplan\gen_angular\arinc_424_19_db\multi\src\manage.py", line 22, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\emin\Desktop\fliteplan\gen_angular\arinc_424_19_db\multi\src\manage.py", line 13, in main
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have a virtual environment whenever saving new dependencies, most importantly django.

```sh
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate

pip install django

// save the dependency
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

**Note the syntax, virtualenv [env name] env can be any name but you would still activate it from [env name]/bin/activate*

Answer (score 0):

Did you active your virtual environment?
If didn't then you can follow this solution to do that
[here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142774/how-to-activate-virtual-environment-in-django)

And if still unable to install Django then check your python installation.
if python is working perfectly then try

```
python -m pip install django
```

and according to your os, you can follow this official documentation link
[official documentation of Django to install](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/install/)

**Thanks**